# Positioning on Canvas with multiple sockets

Tags: node.js, socket.io, html5-canvas, p5.js

So I am trying to make a node multiplayer game using socket.io and the HTML5 canvas.
I have gotten the objects to appear on each other's client canvas, but their positions are way off. How do I position the objects so that they will show up properly on the client side?

Here is my code. 
Client:

```
var socket;
var ship;
var cnv;

function setup() {

 cnv = createCanvas(1000, 1000);
 translate(120, 120);
 var x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
 var y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
 cnv.position(x, y);
  background(51);
  socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
  ship = new Avatar();
   socket.on('pos', newDrawing)

   var data = {
     x:ship.pos.x,
     y:ship.pos.y,
     r:ship.r,
     heading:ship.heading
   }
   socket.emit('start', data)
}

 function newDrawing(data){
  for(var i =0; i< data.length;i++){
    if(data[i].id != socket.id){
      rotate(data[i].h+ PI/2)
      var x=data[i].x;
      var y= data[i].y
      var r = data[i].r

      console.log(r)
      triangle(x+ -data[i].r, y+data[i].r, x+data[i].r,y+data[i].r,x+ 0,y+-data[i].r)
    }
  }
  }


function keyPressed(){

  if(keyCode == 65){
    ship.setRotation(-0.1)
    //ship.vel.x += -speed;
  }
  //Right
  if(keyCode == 68){
    ship.setRotation(0.1)
  }
  if(keyCode == 87){
    ship.boosting(true);
  }

}
function keyReleased(){
  ship.setRotation(0);
  ship.boosting(false);
}

function draw() {
  //background(51);
//console.log(cnv)
ship.render();
ship.turn()
ship.update();
ship.edges();
var data = {
  x:ship.pos.x,
  y:ship.pos.y,
  r:ship.r,
  heading:ship.heading
}

socket.emit('pos', data)
//clear()
}
```

---

Object

```
class Avatar{
  constructor(){
    this.pos=createVector(1000,1000);
    this.r=50;
    this.vel=createVector(0,0)
    this.color = 'red';
    this.move=false;
    this.heading=0;
    this.rotation=0;
    this.isBoost=false;
  }
  update(){
    if(this.isBoost){
      this.boost();
    }
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.vel.mult(.99)
    }
  setRotation(a){
    this.rotation=a;
  }
  boosting(a){
    this.isBoost=a;
  }
  boost(){
    var force= p5.Vector.fromAngle(this.heading);
    this.vel.add(force);
  }
  turn(){
    this.heading+= this.rotation;
  }
  edges(){
    if(this.pos.x>width+this.r){
      this.pos.x=-this.r;
    } else if(this.pos.x<-this.r){
      this.pos.x=width +this.r;
    }
    if(this.pos.y>height+this.r){
      this.pos.y=-this.r;
    } else if(this.pos.y<-this.r){
      this.pos.y=height +this.r;
    }
  }
  render(){
    //clear()
    //translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y)
    rotate(this.heading+ PI/2)
    //rect(this.r,-this.r,this,this.r)
    fill(this.color)
    triangle(-this.r,this.r,this.r,this.r,0,-this.r)
  }
}
```

---

Server

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var server = app.listen(3000)
var ships=[];

function Avatar(id,x,y,r,h){
  this.id=id;
  this.x = x;
  this.y= y;
  this.r=r;
  this.h=h;
}

console.log("Server on %s", server.address().port)
// function listen(){
//   var host= server.address().address;
//   var port= server.address().port;
//   console.log('Server running on %s',port )
// }
app.use(express.static('public'));

var socket=require('socket.io');
var io=socket(server);
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){

  console.log("New Socket:" + socket.id)

  socket.on('start',function(data){
    ships.push(new Avatar(socket.id, data.x, data.y, data.r, data.heading));
    //console.log(ships)
  })

  socket.on('pos',function(data){
    var ship;
    for(var i =0; i< ships.length; i++){
      if(ships[i].id == socket.id){
        ships[i].x=data.x;
        ships[i].y=data.y;
        ships[i].r=data.r;
        ships[i].h=data.heading;
      }
    }
    //console.log(ships[0])
    //console.log(ships)
      //console.log(socket.id)
      //io.sockets.emit('pos',ships)

      socket.broadcast.emit('pos',ships)

  })
  socket.on('disconnect' , function(){

    for(var i =0; i< ships.length; i++){
      if(ships[i].id == socket.id){
        console.log(socket.id + " Has Left")
        ships.splice(i,1);
      }

    }
  })
})
```

Part of the issue I am seeing is that the other clients objects are being drawn as though their point of origin is not in the center of its own object.

Comment: I figured out why it was an issue. I was unaware that the translate and rotate functions were not object specific. Meaning, that when I was rotating for my client, it was rotating the perspective of the canvas, not the object. So any other objects would be visibly rotating around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it was an issue. I was unaware that the translate and rotate functions were not object specific. Meaning, that when I was rotating for my client, it was rotating the perspective of the canvas, not the object. So any other objects would be visibly rotating around it.